# Sustainability Contacts for Educational Facilities

Tags: data-request, data.gov, education

I am looking for a list of the sustainability contacts at universities, colleges and private schools in New York state.

Comment: I voted to close because this is a request for information, not data.

Comment: Voted to keep open because this feels like a valid request for data. An open, aggregated dataset of public contacts (e.g. name, institute, role, domain) feels like it could be useful and if it doesn't exist perhaps it should...

Comment: One use case for this kind of data is in exploring conflicts of interest.